# Right sequence of brackets

Tags: c++, algorithm

Please help with writing program on C++. We have a sequence of brackets. It consists from 4 kinds - (), [], {}, <>. Required to find the shortest sequence with the right placement of brackets, for which the initial sequence would be a subsequence, i. e. would be obtained from the resulting correct sequence by deleting some (possibly zero) number of brackets.

Example:
initial sequence <]}} {([]) 
the answer: <[] {} {} ([]) <>>

Comment: Use context stacks maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed answer doesn't seem to fit the requirements. For example, it doesn't look (at least to me) like you can generate the `}}{` sequence by deleting elements from `<[] {} {} ([]) <>>`. You also seem to have a completely unnecessary pair of angle brackets. Presumably, your intent is also that the brackets in the generated sequence are balanced--otherwise, the correct answer is to simply leave the original sequence unchanged. With no other requirements, that's clearly the shortest sequence from which you can generate that sequence by deleting (zero) items.

If the requirement for balancing is correct, it looks like your original input has four possible correct results:

```
<[]{}{}{([])}>
<[]{}{}{}([])>
<>[]{}{}{}([])
<>[]{}{}{([])}
```

All these are the same length, so I don't see a particular reason to prefer one over the other. This looks enough like homework that I'm not going just give a direct solution to the problem, *but* I think the simplest code you could write for the job would probably produce the first of these four solutions (and that may provide at least some guidance about how I'd solve the problem).

I'm reasonably certain this can be done entirely using counters--shouldn't need any sort of "context stacks" (though a stack-based solution is certainly possible as well).

Comment: Can you give a code, please?

Comment: I could, but since (as noted in my answer) it looks like homework to me, I'm not going to.

Comment: Please, I am doing this program for week and tried so many ideas, but couldn't do